# How to Identify Repeating Data Entries when the Repeated Entries are Spelled or Constructed Differently

Tags: python, r, algorithms, text

I have a dataset of entries and a variable for the owner of the entry. Some of these people occur more than once. However, the names are sometimes written differently. I want to eventually be able to aggregate the other data to the single owner. These are the names of business owners so sometimes it's a singular name, sometimes it's more than one name, and sometimes it's just the company name. Here's an example of some of the styles of names in the data:

- DOE JOHN
- DOE JOHN J
- DOE, JOHN
- DOE, JOHN + JANE
- DOE JOHN + JANE
- JOHN DOE J ETAL % JOHN J DOE
- COMPANY CO

I've never done anything like this before. How could I go about identifying some of the same people? Is there a way to create an index to identify the similarity between these groups? Most of the ones I've seen are for longer text. Is there an index well suited for this?

I apologize if this is too basic a question. I'm new to doing things like this and I'm not sure if I know exactly what to search for. I'm most comfortable with Stata and R but I've used Python before and I could eventually figure out how to do something with that.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric forw ways to check similarity. Typically there will be false positives and false negatives with any method for this kind of data, so don't expect a perfect result. I have a question though: is it possible to use other variables to help identify people? (I have had a similar problem recently, but there were also the birthdate and the place of residence (with other errors as well). The name alone is risky as there can be homonyms.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I think this is all I'm going to get (I'm trying this at the request of someone else who only gave me this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For R: Have a look and the [stringr package](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/). I would use for example the str_detect() function as follows: str_detect(column_of_different_names,"DOE|company_name"). This will return TRUE for each string that includes "DOE" or the company name in "company_name".